# LIBGDX - Texture glitch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm playing around with LIBGDX in Android Studio and I'm trying to insert an image as a texture for my game. I'm using the "badlogic.jpg" that is included for example. The image shows up fine on DesktopLauncher and on my Nexus 7 but on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3, something is wrong. I hope these screenshots explain better: [Samsung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmGi4.jpg) - [Nexus 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lWVg.png)

This is my GameRenderer class in case that helps:

```
    public class GameRenderer {

    public static Texture badLogic;
    private SpriteBatch batch;

    private GameWorld myWorld;

    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
        myWorld = world;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        badLogic = AssetLoader.badLogic;


    }

    public void render(float runTime) {

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(badLogic, 100, 100);
        batch.end();

    }

}
```

And GameScreen:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private GameWorld world;
private GameRenderer renderer;
private float runTime;

public GameScreen() {

    world = new GameWorld();
    renderer = new GameRenderer(world);

}
@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {               
    Gdx.app.log("FPS:", (1 / delta) + "");
    runTime += delta;
    world.update(delta);
    renderer.render(runTime);

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

Is this even an issue with the code or is it my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

to this part in the GameRenderer:

```
    public void render (float runTime) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(badLogic, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have made your Texture static

```
     public static Texture badLogic;
```

it should be

```
     public Texture badLogic;
```

Android has issues with unloading static content after end of application life cycle and that's why you see these glitches

Comment: This didn't change anything visually but I will keep this in mind. Sorted the problem myself so don't worry about that. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah. This is a partial solution to the problem but it is good to know. ALWAYS dispose everything static or you will face weird problems.